# ActiveMQ Transport Protocol: amqps vs ampq+ssl

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, messaging, amqp

I try to consume messages from an ActiveMQ server via amqp protocol. Since there is a lot going on with ActiveMQ and the switch from javax.jms to jakarta.jms and the detach from the Spring-Boot v3 version I came up with the following setup:

```
//plugin
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'

//dependencies
implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '6.0.8'
implementation group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-client-jakarta', version: '5.18.1'
```

I create a `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` bean for the required `jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory` which seems to work fine.

With this said, my acutal problem is, that I run into a transport protocol issue. I figured out that when I import

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-amqp', version: '5.18.1'
```

I can consume messages with amqp protocol. But what I still am missing is a transport protocol for amqps, because the actual url I want to consume provides access with amqps. So I actually have two questions:

1. What is the difference from amqps and amqp+ssl (which is provided by the lib)
2. Where can I find the amqps transport protocol

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `org.apache.activemq:activemq-client-jakarta` nor `org.apache.activemq:activemq-amqp` provide a client implementation for AMQP. The `org.apache.activemq:activemq-client-jakarta` dependency provides a Jakarta Messaging client implementation which uses the OpenWire protocol. The `org.apache.activemq:activemq-amqp` dependency provides a server-side implementation of AMQP used by ActiveMQ "Classic" (i.e. the broker). You'd configure `amqp+ssl` for the `transportConnector` in `activemq.xml` if you wanted the broker to support AMQP connections over SSL.

If you want to use AMQP via Jakarta Messaging from Spring I recommend using [Qpid JMS](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html). There's [a handy "starter" for Spring Boot](https://github.com/amqphub/amqp-10-jms-spring-boot) as well.

You can find the AMQP specification [here](https://www.amqp.org/resources/download). `amqps` is nothing more than normal AMQP over SSL so there is no specification specifically for it.

Keep in mind that ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't implement all of the functionality from JMS 2 & Jakarta Messaging 3. If you need a full implementation at this point you should use [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (which is [directly supported in Spring Boot 3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.jms.artemis)).

Comment: Ok, so I mixed up client which uses OpenWire Protocol and not AMQP and tried to tweak it with a server-side implementation. So thanks for the clarification, it looks like it really was necessary. I will have a look into QPID JMS which seems suitable for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for someone stumbling over this thread. I found this spring-boot-starter which brings an quite
easy way to use AMQP(S) via QPID and spring-boot v3

https://github.com/amqphub/amqp-10-jms-spring-boot

Got it running in a flash.

Comment: I added this link to my answer for completeness. Thanks for following up.